# Woocommerce add Menu category and sub menu single page product

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

i am building a page, and when i enter a single product page the category menu of woocommerce disappear on the single product page. how can i add the menu that is on this page "http://zdk.pt/maisuniforme/loja/" beneath the title "Loja" to the top of every single product page ? (" ex: http://zdk.pt/maisuniforme/loja/industrial-construcao/calcao/") I tried to add menu on the functions.php of woocommerce but i failed and had to reinstall everything can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is different version of header calling inside your `single-product.php` file.

You can check the `single-product.php` inside `your theme/woocommerce/` folder or inside your `plugin/woocommerce/templates/` folder and check `get_header()` Change the `single-product.php` header to your default header or you can also call menu inside your custom header called on `single-product.php`

Comment: so i change on the single-product.php "get_header('shop');" for this? " <?php get_header(); ?>
Correct?

Comment: yeah that's the issue. change it back to get_header(); from 'shop';

Comment: Thank you. but on the single-product.php the header is get_head('shop'); i change this code right? sorry for not understanding :s

Comment: Yes change <?php get_header('shop'); ?> to <?php get_header(); ?> , Thanks :)

Comment: Hope it will help you , accept the answer if it helps you, thank you.